# Можно ли найти хостинг провайдера по ip на c#?

Tags: c#, .net, ip, hosting

Можно ли найти хостинг провайдера по ip с помощью c#? Я знаю что есть подобные сторонние сервисы но возможно ли самостоятельно автоматизировать?

Comment: Язык программирования не важен, главное алгоритм знать.

Comment: whois сервис например